# C++ multidimensional data visualization

Tags: c++, visualization

For a dataset of `N` records and `M` columns (features), I want to visualize it in 2d or 3d. Does anyone know if such a c++ library exists?

Comment: This question needs more information. What type of visualisation do you have in mind?

Comment: @MatthewLueder Well, I need a way to down scale multidimensional data to 2d or 3d.

Comment: I do not know about any good solution. You can visualize data using ```QT``` in C++, or just use another, in my opinion easier solution  - save data to a file, and then plot then with ```matplotlib```, ```gnuplot``` or something similar, not using C++.

Comment: @wair92 That's exactly what I want to avoid. So far I use matlab to do this kind of things. I was wondering if there is a c++ solution.

Comment: So you want to do something like a PCA?

Comment: @MatthewLueder Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MatthewLueder's comment pointing out the `PCA`, I found [libpca](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpca/).

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want online plotting. That is, animation plot at runtime, correct?

If so, then there are few libraries and one of which is gnuplot-iostream http://www.stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/. I use it and recommend it. It requires the Boost library however.

Otherwise, you can write your data on files and use in a subsequent step a visualizer of your choice. Again, gnuplot is very powerful.

Comment: Thank you, I 'll give a try